# A Really Basic Infinite Sum Problem (This might also be a geometric series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm not really sure how I should go about this problem:

$\displaystyle \frac{x-1}{x} +\frac{x-2}{x} +\frac{x-3}{x} \ .\ .\ .\ +\frac{1}{x} =3,\ x\in ℕ$

I tried multiplying by x on both sides, but this just results in 3 being equal to infinity times x.

Comment: Do you know how to add $(x-1)+(x-2)+(x-3)+\dots+1$?

Comment: It might help if you look at it in the other order... $1+2+3+\dots+(x-2)+(x-1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, unfortunately I don't

Comment: $1+2+3+\dots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is a "[triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)."  Familiarize yourself with the result and the proof of the result, as the technique used in proving it is useful for proving other things.

Comment: @SacredCobalt:    $1+2+3+\cdots n$ is arithmetic, not geometric, series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The sum of the numerators is $\dfrac {x(x-1)}2$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that\begin{align}\frac{x-1}x+\frac{x-2}x+\cdots+\frac1x&=\left(1-\frac1x\right)+\left(1-\frac2x\right)+\cdots+\left(1-\frac{x-1}x\right)\\&=x-1-\frac1x\bigl(1+2+\cdots+(x-1)\bigr)\\&=x-1-\frac1x\times\frac{x(x-1)}2\\&=\frac{x-1}2.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much! It didn't click for me that this was a triangular number.